# Osmc CEC not working after using cec-client in ssh terminal

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, kodi

I have a RPI2 with OSMC installed and I want to do some cec commands to check if the Tv is ON or OFF.

The issue is that after any command cec-client ( except cec-client -h :) ) the OSMC won't receive CEC commands until I restart the RPI. Is there any way to reconnect OSMC with the CEC? Cec service is still running, but OSMC does not recognize  it;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
xbmc-send -a 'CECActivateSource'
```

This way xbmc will connect again with the cec service. If it doesn't work you can always restart osmc via ssh (but it's not pretty at all)